# ROS Qt Creator Plug-in installation error

Tags: ros, plugin, ros-kinetic, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am on ubuntu 16.04.
I am trying to install ROS Qt Creator Plug-in (I followed steps of ROS industrial tutorial) but when I try to launch qtcreator-ros (as showed in plug-in step), I get the following errors :

```
axyn@axyn-ubuntu:~$ qtcreator-ros 
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

Does someone know what my problem is ?
Thanks a lot !
Cécile

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295969/ros-qt-creator-plug-in-installation-error/) by [cecrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/36197/cecrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-07-02**:
It looks like qtcreator is failing to find the radeon graphics driver (or a part of it). I would check that your graphics drivers are set up correctly.

**Comment by [cecrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/36197/cecrap/) on 2018-07-05**:
I tried to fix problems with drivers but impossible to update them. I maybe have a problem between ubuntu version 16.04 and last qtcreator version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I just want to confirm that you followed the install procedure found in the link below? Also, what architecture are you installing it on (x86, arm64, etc.)?

https://ros-industrial.github.io/ros_qtc_plugin/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html

---

Originally posted by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) with karma: 106 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cecrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/36197/cecrap/) on 2018-07-02**:
Hi, yes I followed the procedure of this link. My architecture is x86_64 GNU/Linux.
Cécile